# Log normal distribution

Tags: python, statistics

I have a question regarding lognormal distribution. I want to create and ensemble of objects with "masses" from 10 to 10**5 that are normally distributed. I thought this would be a a lognormal distribution and so I started trying to do this in python like so:

```
mu, sigma = 3., 1. # mean and standard deviation
s = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 1000, density=True, align='mid')
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 1000)
pdf = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
plt.plot(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

as is shown in the example from numpy, but changing mu and sigma and looking at the plots, I can't really tell if setting m and v (following the wikipedia article linked below) to 10**5 and 1000 lets say gives me what I want

I looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution to figure out how to calculate mu and sigma, but maybe im doing something else wrong. Is this the right approach to this problem?

I read previous questions/answers regarding the lognormal distribution, but i don't think they asked the same thing. Sorry in advanced if this type of question has already been answered.

mu, sigma = 3., 1. Is what's given in the example, This works fine, but when i change mu and sigma to values like:

```
m=10**3.5 #where I want the distribution to be centered
v=10000   #the "spread" that I want 
f=1.+(v/m2)
mu=np.log(m/np.sqrt(f))
sigma=np.sqrt(np.log(f))
```

I don't get what i expected.. which is a distribution centered around 10**3.5 with a std of 10000.

Trying what was suggested:

```
mu=np.log(3000)
sigma=np.log(10)
s = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 500, density=True, align='mid')
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 1000)
pdf = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
plt.semilogx(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
```

This doesn't seem to work either, unless im misinterpreting the histogram
[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTwBt.png)

Comment: Your question lacks a clear problem statement? What exactly do you want? The wiki gives a relation between m,v and mu, sigma. You mention the values of m, v in your question but nowhere in your code are you using them. Be specific and clear please. Why do you choose mu=3 and sigma=1?

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question. The 3 and the one were just the values in the example in the documentation of np.random.lognormal()

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having difficulty interpreting the parameters of the distribution.

The documentation for np.random.lognormal is here: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html

In particular, the mean is not `mu` or `10**mu`, but `exp(mu)`, so your distribution as given has a mean of `e**3 ≈ 20`.

You seem to want the mean to be about 1000, so setting mu and sigma to

```
mu, sigma  = np.log(1000), np.log(10)`
```

will generate the distribution that you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks, yes, i think not understanding the variables is definitely the issue that im having. I tried doing what you suggested thought and the plot of the histogram still seems off

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you want 1000 values that are log-normally distributed distribution (i.e., log(x) gives you normal distribution), and you want your data to range from 10 to 10^5, then you have to do some calculations to get mu and sigma.  But the values you have to plug into `np.random.lognormal` are the mean and standard deviation of the underlying, related **normal** distribution, **not** the log-normal distribution.  You can derive these from the mean and variance formulas given on the Wikipedia page you saw.

```
# Parameters
xmax = 10**5
xmin = 10
n = 1000

# Get original mean and variance
# mu: We want normal distribution, so just take the average of the extremes.
# sigma: use the z = (x - mu)/sigma formula and approximation that 
#        the extremes are a deviation of z=3 away.
mu = (xmax + xmin)/2.0
sigma = (xmax - mu)/3.0
m = mu
v = sigma**2

# Get the mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution
norm_mu = np.log(m**2 / np.sqrt(v + m**2))
norm_sigma = np.sqrt((v / m**2)+1)

# Generate random data and an overlying smooth curve
# (This is the same as your code, except I replaced the parameters
# in the 'pdf =' formula.)
s = np.random.lognormal(norm_mu, norm_sigma, n)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, n, density=True, align='mid')
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), n)
pdf = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - norm_mu)**2 / (2 * norm_sigma**2)) / (x * norm_sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
plt.plot(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Here's what I get.  Notice the scaling on the x-axis goes up exponentially, not linearly.  Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Thats, what i want except shifted so that its centered round 10**3 or 10**3.5. However changing mu in your example seems to break it which i don't understand. Also I think you have a m**2 instead of m when calculating norm_mu. Thanks again